# How to save value once user selects a result from typeahead.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

Question I would like to grab the value of the state once the user selects a state from the list. I have the following so far it doesn't seem to work.

```
  $('form').on("change", ".state", function(e){
    var $contextualDiv = $(e.target).closest('div');
    var $state = $contextualDiv.find('.state');
    console.log($state.typeahead('val'));
    ...
```

$state.val() seems to be an typeahead object that I can't access. I also don't want the user to click outside the inputbox before jquery saves the value, only as soon as the user selects a result from the suggestion list.

This is my current code:

html:

```
<form>
    <div>
      <input class="state tt-input">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="state tt-input">
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

jquery/typeahead.js implementation:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var bh = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: {
          url: '/get_states/',
          prefetch: function(settings) {
            settings.type = "GET";
            return settings;
          }, 
        },
      });

  $('.state').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'states',
      source: bh,
  });

  var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
      return function findMatches(q, cb) {
      var matches, substringRegex;

      // an array that will be populated with substring matches
      matches = [];

      // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
      substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

      // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
      // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
      $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
        if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
          matches.push(str);
        }
      });

      cb(matches);
    };
  };
```

[image: Typeahead object]

[image: Value is correct.]

Answer (score 0):

Try  `console.log($state.typeahead('val'))`

see [documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md)

in this case you have a array of objects to get the values you do a loop:

```
$state.each(function(i,v){
   console.log($(v).val());//or console.log($(v).typeahead('val'))
})
```

to get o**nly the current changed state** you do the following:

```
 $('form').on("change", ".state", function(e){
    console.log($(this).val());
    ...
```

Comment: I tried that but I still get the object not the value.

Comment: can't you get the value from the object, can you paste the object in your question?

Comment: Not sure how to do that. It's in my java console in my browser.

Comment: do a printscreen

Comment: printscreen added. please just replace $state with $airline. It used the same code for another active project.

Comment: Am I implementing this incorrectly where I need to iterate through the object vs. following what is in the documentation?

Comment: you have multiple inputs so you need a loop to get all the values

Comment: I only have one active. Having multiple active input is actually a question I will put in another post. I think the [0] entry in the array is when the user is entering the input. It shouldn't exist. All of the data in that object is null.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle so i can see the problem better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151596/discussion-between-h-c-and-madalin-ivascu).

Comment: I create the jsfiddle as requested.